# post form to iframe and echo result text on parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, iframe

On my site I have a form that posts to an iframe, both parent and iframe window is on my page, domain, etc.

```
<iframe id="ifc1" style="display:none;" name="ifc"></iframe>

<div id="couponbox">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="promo-form" class="form-inline" action="" method="post" target="ifc">
    <div class="form-group">            
        <input type="text" name="..." placeholder="Enter Here" id="..." class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Apply Now" placeholder="">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

The form is posting successfully, and on the iframe page there is a div that shows the alert/results.

```
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-success">.....</div>
```

I am trying to use JS or Jquery to find which text is showing in the alert (ie. fail, success, etc.), and then echo a message on the parent page.

```
// Attempt at a supposed solution 

// reference to iframe with id 'ifrm'
var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifc1');
var base = document.getElementById('couponbox');
// using reference to iframe (ifrm) obtained above
var win = ifrm.contentWindow; // reference to iframe's window
// reference to document in iframe
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
// reference to form named 'demoForm' in iframe
var form = doc.getElementById('alert');

if (form === "Credits successfully deposited into your account") {
// Tried jQuery 
$('#couponbox').append('success')
}

// jQuery attempt
if($("#ifc1").contents().text().search("successfully deposited")!=-1){
    alert("found");
}
```

So far I haven't been able to get anything to work. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE --

I am currently trying to use this code --

```
$('#ifc1').on('load', function() {

if($.trim($("#ifc1").contents().find("#alert").html()) === "Credits successfully deposited into your account"){
       $("#couponbox").prepend("<b>Successfully Deposited</b>");
$("#buy").replaceWith( '<input type="submit" value="Publish" name="upsub" id="upsub" class="pubbtn action-button" placeholder="">' 

  } else {
$("#ifc1").contents().find("#alert").appendTo("#couponbox");
}
});
```

I've placed it at the end of my page. It's giving me errors with my other scripts though.

Commenting out the replacewith function, doesn't give the looping error ---

```
$('#ifc1').on('load', function() {

if($.trim($("#ifc1").contents().find("#alert").html()) === "Credits successfully deposited into your account"){
       $("#couponbox").prepend("<b>Successfully Deposited</b>");
//$("#buy").replaceWith( '<input type="submit" value="Publish" name="upsub" id="upsub" class="pubbtn action-button" placeholder="">' 

  } else {
$("#couponbox").prepend("<b>Incorrect</b>");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text of `#alert` div from iframe you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ifc1").contents().find("form#promo-form").on("submit",function(){
      alert($("#ifc1").contents().find("#alert").html());
  });    
});
```

It will give you the text in `#alert` div.

### Update

```
$('#ifc1').on('load', function() {
     alert($("#ifc1").contents().find("#alert").html());
});
```

When you submit a form in iframe it also triggers load event of iframe. Check if you can get a value on load function?

### Update 2

```
    $('#ifc1').on('load', function() {
         if($.trim($("#ifc1").contents().find("#alert").html()) === "success"){
            alert("finish");
         }
    });
```

you can use $.trim to remove all white spaces around the string and the check if it matches with "success". [TRIM](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

Comment: It comes back undefined and it alerts on submit but also fires on parent page load before the form is ever submitted to the iframe.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if it works also can you please tell me how you are submitting the form? Using AJAX or a submit button? @Rich

Comment: I tried the new code but it didnt do anything. And Im submitting the form using a submit button.

Comment: Please check update in my answer. Also in my old code I forget to add # before ifc1. @Rich

Comment: Ahhh! Your updated code seems to work. Im doing some more testing, if it checks out then I will accept your answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to compare the text so that I can output a different text on the parent page? For example, "if text = success, echo = finish"

Comment: Check update 2 please. Let me know if it works or not. @Rich

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the contents of the form element, but you're not using `innerHTML`.

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifc1');
var base = document.getElementById('couponbox');
var win = ifrm.contentWindow; // reference to iframe's window
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
var form = doc.getElementById('alert');

if (form.innerHTML.includes("Credits successfully deposited into your account")) {
$('#couponbox').append('success')
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it gave me this error --  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`